# how to take clear photo from google maps

Tags: google-maps

I'd like to know, if it's possible to take a photo from google street view, but without all of these buttons and so on. I need to pick up just a clean photo. Could anyone tell me if it's possible, and if it is how can I do this?Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I think the easiest way is to PrintScreen the view youd want to save. Put it in a new Paint file, and cut out all the extras that you don't need.